# Can I make Control-U behavior be the same for ZSH as it is for Bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

In Bash, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> will clear from the cursor to the beginning of the line, and put that text into the paste buffer, which can be pasted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

In Zsh, it will clear the text, but does not put it into the buffer.

Sadness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done really easily with just two `bindkey` commands:

```
bindkey '^U' backward-kill-line
bindkey '^Y' yank
```

It may be worth noting that at least '^Y' should be bound in the default Emacs keymap.

Comment: yes! worked like a charm. before it was set to kill-whole-line

Comment: Using Backspace clears yank buffer (unlike bash). It makes Ctrl+U Ctrl+Y almost useless.